# Convert rows to one based on a common name

Tags: r

I have many stock data but in a strange way which I couldn't find an example how to convert them to the output which could helpful.  Here is a snippet of data

```
stockname,value,prediction
Yahoo,32,12
Yahoo,21,12
Yahoo,30,10
Yahoo,56,19
Google,32,10
Google,22,30
```

Is it possible to convert this dataframe to something easier like

```
stockname value1 value2 value3 value4 prediction1 prediction2 prediction3 prediction4
Yahoo       32     21     30     56     12            12           10         19
Google      32     22                   10            10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `dcast` from the devel version of `data.table` ie. `v1.9.5+`, which can take multiple `value.var` columns.  Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(df1)[, indx:=1:.N, stockname]#create a sequence index by stockname
dcast(df1, stockname~indx, value.var=c('value', 'prediction'))
#  stockname value_1 value_2 value_3 value_4 prediction_1 prediction_2
#1:    Google      32      22      NA      NA           10           30
#2:     Yahoo      32      21      30      56           12           12
#   prediction_3 prediction_4
#1:           NA           NA
#2:           10           19
```

Comment: Unfortunately until now I can install the version #v1.9.5+ maybe I have to install first the Github?

Comment: @Stef32 You need `library(devtools)` installed first

Comment: Yes I made it. It has installed. It only gives a warning to install R tools but I didn't make it.

Comment: @Ster32 Which version of R you have?  I am using `R 3.2.0` in `linux` and the newest is `R 3.2.1`.  As mentioned in the link, the windows users should install `Rtools`

Comment: @Ster32 Another option is `library(reshape2);df2 <- transform(df1, indx=ave(stockname, stockname, FUN=seq_along)); recast(df2, id.var=c('stockname', 'indx'),stockname~variable+indx, value.var='value')`

Comment: @Ster32, as mentioned in the webpage akrun linked to, you've to have R tools installed first..

Answer (score 5):

This is a simple problem of reshaping data from "long" to "wide". Here's a base R solution using `reshape`:

```
# load data
d <- read.csv(text="stockname,value,prediction
Yahoo,32,12
Yahoo,21,12
Yahoo,30,10
Yahoo,56,19
Google,32,10
Google,22,30", header = TRUE)

# create a time indicator variable
d$t <- c(1:4, 1:2)
# reshape
reshape(d, idvar="stockname", direction="wide", timevar = "t")
#   stockname value.1 prediction.1 value.2 prediction.2 value.3 prediction.3 value.4 prediction.4
# 1     Yahoo      32           12      21           12      30           10      56           19
# 5    Google      32           10      22           30      NA           NA      NA           NA
```

Comment: as I can understand d$t is the 4 values and 2 are the two rows in the result I have. As I mention this is an example in the dataset I don't know the specific numbe of the new rows and columns.

Comment: @Ster32 You actually didn't mention that anywhere.